# Gradle cannot find com.linitix:toolkit:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I got the project and I have the error message : 
`Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.linitix:toolkit:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.
         Required by:
         tapmeet:basemodule:unspecified`

The plugin version is 2.1.2 and Gradle version is 2.10.

Do I miss a Url ?